# MongooseJS modify document during pre hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, compoundjs

I'm having some issues with mongoose. My goal is that during pre-save, I would be able to modify the object, doing things like splitting the tags if needed, or in another case calculating the summation of a sub-document durations and update it within the main document.

What I'm finding is that if I load a model, then call doc.update passing the new data, only `schema.pre('update', ...)` triggers, and any changes to `this` within my middleware are not updated. I also tried using `this.set('...', ....);` within my update middleware to no avail.

It seems if I do `doc.save(...)` instead, then changes to `this` within `schema.pre('save', ...)` are appended as expected. Aside from extending the posted variables into my model's properties and saving, I'm not seeing any way of leveraging doc.update for this purpose.

My Goals:
- Update an existing document via `doc.update(properties, ....)`
- Use middleware during saving to modify the document, do advanced validation, and update related documents
- Use middleware during updating to modify the document, do advanced validation, and update related documents
- Interchangeably use model.findByIdAndUpdate, model.save, model.findById->doc.update, model.findById->doc.save and all tap into my save/update middleware.

Some arbitrary sample code:

```
function loadLocation(c) {
    var self = this;
    c.Location.findById(c.params.id, function(err, location) {
        c.respondTo(function(format) {
            if (err | !location) {
                format.json(function() {
                    c.send(err ? {
                        code: 500,
                        error: err
                    } : {
                        code: 404,
                        error: 'Location Not Found!'
                    });
                });
                format.html(function() {
                    c.redirect(c.path_to.admin_locations);
                });
            } else {
                self.location = location;
                c.next();
            }
        });
    });
}

LocationController.prototype.update = function update(c) {
    var location = this.location;
    this.title = 'Edit Location Details';

    location.update(c.body.Location, function(err) {
        c.respondTo(function(format) {
            format.json(function() {
                c.send(err ? {
                    code: 500,
                    error: location && location.errors || err
                } : {
                    code: 200,
                    location: location.toObject()
                });
            });
            format.html(function() {
                if (err) {
                    c.flash('error', JSON.stringify(err));
                } else {
                    c.flash('info', 'Location updated');
                }
                c.redirect(c.path_to.admin_location(location.id));
            });
        });
    });
};

module.exports = function(compound) {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        address: String,
        tags: [{ type: String, index: true }],
        geo: {
            type: {
                type: String,
            default:
                "Point"
            },
            coordinates: [Number] // Longitude, Latitude
        }
    });
    schema.index({
        geo: '2dsphere'
    });
    var Location = mongoose.model('Location', schema);
    Location.modelName = 'Location';
    compound.models.Location = Location;

    schema.pre('save', function(next) {
        if(typeof this.tags === 'string') {
            this.tags = this.tags.split(',');
        }
    });
};
```

==== *** revised sample *** ====

```
module.exports = function(compound) {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        bio: String
    });

    schema.pre('save', function(next) {
        console.log('Saving...');
        this.bio = "Tristique sed magna tortor?"; 
        next();
    });

    schema.pre('update', function(next) {
        console.log('Updating...');
        this.bio = "Quis ac, aenean egestas?"; 
        next();
    });

    var Author = mongoose.model('Author', schema);
    Author.modelName = 'Author';
    compound.models.Location = Author;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

`pre` hooks work for both `doc.save()` and `doc.update()`. In both cases `this` refers to the document itself.

Note that hooks need to be added to your schema before compiling your model.

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if(typeof this.tags === 'string') {
        this.tags = this.tags.split(',');
    }
});
var Location = mongoose.model('Location', schema);
```

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't help that I created poor sample code. I tried your recommendation with a simpler case and am still getting the same results: after looking up a doc with `Author.findById`, when I call `author.update(c.req.body, ...)`, `schema.pre('save', ...)` does not trigger, however `schema.pre('update', ...)` does and the changes to `this.name` aren't being applied. `schema.pre('save', ...)` should trigger no?

It does look like author.save triggers `schema.pre('save', ...)` and changes made then are being applied. Is the solution here to just abandon `author.update` altogether?

Comment: correct. `doc.update()` will not trigger hooks for any other method but the one being called.

Comment: Ok, but this still answer the original question. Changings during `schema.pre('update', ...)` still aren't being appended. Is this a bug, intended, or should I simply be exclusively using doc.save and using some method to iterate over my req.body and merge properties?

Comment: Not a bug. `document.update(doc, cb)` sends an update for the passed doc, not the currently changed values. Thats different from `document.save()`.

Comment: If you look at the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html it doesn't mention that schema.pre('update' event is valid.  It only lists init, save, remove and validate.

Comment: @aaronheckmann are you sure that this refers to the current doc ?

Comment: how can i use this with arrow functions (ES6)?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose doesn't support hooks to the Model Update API. However, an update hook can be done via Monkey-patch. The Hooker NPM package is a good way of doing this cleanly.

The [RESTeasy](https://github.com/LiveRelay/RESTeasy) project which is a Boilerplate for Node REST APIs has code that demonstrates how to do it:

```
var hooker = require('hooker');

var BaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sampleString: {
    type: String
  }
});

var BaseModel = mongoose.model('Base', BaseSchema);

// Utilize hooks for update operations. We do it in this way because MongooseJS
// does not natively support update hooks at the Schema level. This is a way
// to support it.
hooker.hook (BaseModel, 'update', {
  pre: function () {
    // Insert any logic you want before updating to occur here
    console.log('BaseModel pre update');
  },
  post: function () {
    // Insert any logic you want after updating to occur here
    console.log('BaseModel post update');
  }
});

// Export the Mongoose model
module.exports = BaseModel;
```

Comment: Now `update` hooks work natively in Mongoose 4.0, but they are turned off by default.  This blog post explains:   https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm